# How to use bfg-repo-cleaner after Git rebase on non-bare repo?

Tags: git, rebase, bfg-repo-cleaner

### Overview

I have Git repo which serves as an archive for a number of configs sourced from elsewhere:

- 200 dirs
- 100 files per dir
- 10K plain text per file
- ~1000 commits per day, usually < 10 lines edited
- 1 branch
- 1 user handles all commits
- all other view repo on read-only basis

Before anyone suggest I try breaking up this repo into smaller ones, that's not an option because customers.

The repo contains ~2 years worth of data but our customers only need last 90 days.

### Process

I have successfully grafted the root onto a commit 90 days ago using the method described [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Purging-old-history-td7423795.html):

- git checkout -b newroot xyz_90_days_old_rev
- git reset abc_original_root_rev
- git add .
- git commit --amend -m 'purge history'
- git checkout master
- git rebase --onto newroot xyz_90_days_old_rev

The problem is using git-filter-branch cleanup afterwards - it takes > 24 hours which is unacceptable downtime to users.

I would like to try bfg-repo-cleaner instead, but it's not clear to me:

- does it support this use case?
- does it work on a non-bare repo?

**PS**: I am now aware that `git checkout --orphan` would have been slightly more elegant, but it doesn't really change the problem that `BFG` requires the repo be bare while `checkout` requires it not be bare

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother rewriting the repo.  If someone only needs the last 90 days, run a script to estimate the required depth and have them create a shallow clone with `--depth <depth>`.

BFG should be run on a mirror/bare clone.